# Not able to set Hibernate time?

Tags: sleep, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

Recently bought a new laptop Asus TUF Gaming F15. Problem that i am facing is that after i put my laptop to sleep, it automatically shuts down after an hour or so(it basically hibernates). Tried to change the time after which hibernate occurs, but couldn't find those in advanced settings.

Advanced settings :

[image]

`powercfg/a` :

[image]

Comment: See if there is a Hybrid Suspend setting.   I turned this OFF on my Lenovo Laptop and allow Suspend to run until I wake it up. I have tested overnight suspend

Comment: Na there isnt a setting like that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You will need to ask ASUS Supply for a way to separate suspend and hibernate

Comment: To disable hibernation, if that's your wish, run Command Prompt as Administrator and enter the following command: `powercfg.exe /hibernate off`. This will also disable Fast startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Power Options is missing the "Hibernate after" option.
You can force-add the option back with this command in an
elevated command prompt:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364 /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

This may need a reboot to take effect.

Source :
[Add or Remove Hibernate after from Power Options in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108391-add-remove-hibernate-after-power-options-windows.html).

---

If the "Hibernate after" option did not help or work, you may
disable hibernation totally : Run Command Prompt as Administrator and
enter the following command:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

Note that this will also disable Fast startup.

---

If you don't wish to disable Fast startup, you could, instead of
disabling hibernation totally, to set the hibernation
file to a format that supports Fast startup but not hibernation.

See the article
[How to Specify Hiberfile Type as Full or Reduced in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/25151-specify-hiberfile-type-full-reduced-windows-10-a.html),
where is described how to set the hibernation file to either of the
following formats:

> **Full** = Supports being able to enable hibernate and turn on fast startup (hiberboot). The hiberfile (C:\hiberfil.sys) will be 40% of
> physical RAM installed on your computer. Hibernate is available to be
> added to the power menu.
>
> **Reduced** = Only supports being able to turn on fast startup (hiberboot) without hibernate. The hiberfile (C:\hiberfil.sys) will be
> 20% of physical RAM installed on your computer. Removes hibernate from
> the power menu.

This is done in an elevated command prompt by the following two commands:

```
powercfg /h /type reduced
powercfg /h /type full
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked for me!